# JSONArray eliminar duplicidades-

Tags: php, json, array

Dado un JSONArray con varios JSONObects dentro con la siguiente estructura:

```
    [ 
      {"Id_temp":"1","temperatura":"20","Insertado_temp":"2016-08-16 12:30:29"},
      {"Id_press":"1","presion":"34","Insertado_press":"2016-08-16 16:18:36"},
      {"Id_press":"1","presion":"34","Insertado_press":"2016-08-16 16:18:36"},
      {"Id_temp":"1","temperatura":"20","Insertado_temp":"2016-08-16 12:30:29"},
      {"Id_temp":"2","temperatura":"25","Insertado_temp":"2016-08-16 15:48:53"},
      {"Id_press":"2","presion":"34","Insertado_press":"2016-08-16 16:18:36"},
      {"Id_temp":"4","temperatura":"50","Insertado_temp":"2016-08-16 18:17:33"},
      {"Id_temp":"1","temperatura":"20","Insertado_temp":"2016-08-16 12:30:29"}
    ]
```

que he obtenido a partir de el siguiente código:

```
array_push($result,array(
//Pushing name and id in the blank array created
        "Id_temp"=>$row['Id_temp'],
        "temperatura"=>$row['temperatura'],
        "Insertado_temp"=>$row['Insertado_temp'],
        "Id_press"=>$row['Id_press'],
        "presion"=>$row['presion'],
        "Insertado_press"=>$row['Insertado_press']

    ));
$result1 = array_unique ($result);
}
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result1));

mysqli_close($con);
```

Deseo en PHP eliminar los objetos que tengan Id_temp duplicados y Id_press y que se guarde de nuevo en un array. Lo he intentado con "array_unique" y "array_values" pero no me funcionó. Alguien me podría poner un ejemplo basado en este que describo.
Muchas gracias

Comment: Revisa esta [respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23508220/4092887). en caso de que no te funcione la respuesta, te sugiero realizar esta búsqueda _si no la has realizado_: [remove duplicates from json array](https://www.google.com.co/#q=remove%20duplicates%20from%20json%20array&rct=j)

Comment: Por favor califica la respusta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el siguiente ejemplo aplico la siguiente metodología:

Recorrer el array de valores y guardar en 2 arrays separados `$array_temp_fixed` y `$array_press_fixed` los valores únicos interpretando que los valores que no se deben repetir son `Id_temp` y `Id_press`.

Esto lo logro generando 2 arrays donde voy guardando, por separado, los valores de las claves `Id_temp` y `Id_press`. Antes de guardar estos valores únicos, verifico que no existan en el array que corresponda.

Cuando identifico que un valor no existe en mis array únicos lo agrego para que la siguiente vez que se ejecute el ciclo no ingrese en este condicional, esto lo valido utilizando la función in_array que busca un valor determinado `Id_temp / Id_press` dentro del array especificado. En el mismo paso guardo en el array final `$array_fixed` el row completo para su posterior uso.

Por ultimo, solo para facilitar la comprensión imprimo en pantalla los 4 arrays en el siguiente orden:

1. Array original
2. Array de los valores unicos del key Id_temp
3. Array de los valores unicos del key Id_press
4. Array final incluyendo todos los rows sin duplicidad

---

```
 <?php

$json = '[ 
      {"Id_temp":"1","temperatura":"20","Insertado_temp":"2016-08-16 12:30:29"},
      {"Id_press":"1","presion":"34","Insertado_press":"2016-08-16 16:18:36"},
      {"Id_press":"1","presion":"34","Insertado_press":"2016-08-16 16:18:36"},
      {"Id_temp":"1","temperatura":"20","Insertado_temp":"2016-08-16 12:30:29"},
      {"Id_temp":"2","temperatura":"25","Insertado_temp":"2016-08-16 15:48:53"},
      {"Id_press":"2","presion":"34","Insertado_press":"2016-08-16 16:18:36"},
      {"Id_temp":"4","temperatura":"50","Insertado_temp":"2016-08-16 18:17:33"},
      {"Id_temp":"1","temperatura":"20","Insertado_temp":"2016-08-16 12:30:29"}
    ]';

$array = json_decode($json, true);
$array_temp_fixed = array();
$array_press_fixed = array();
$array_fixed = array();

foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if (!empty($value["Id_temp"]) && !in_array($value["Id_temp"], $array_temp_fixed)){
        $array_temp_fixed[] = $value["Id_temp"];
        $array_fixed[] = $value;
    }
    if (!empty($value["Id_press"]) && !in_array($value["Id_press"], $array_press_fixed)){
        $array_press_fixed[] = $value["Id_press"];
        $array_fixed[] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($array);
print_r($array_temp_fixed);
print_r($array_press_fixed);
print_r($array_fixed);
?>
```

Comment: Hola Max, ¿puedes explicar un poco el código? cómo funciona o cómo resuelve el problema, sería bueno un poco de texto que lo acompañe. ¿por qué hacerlo de esa manera?

Comment: Hola Shaz, gracias por los comentarios. Acabo de añadir una explicacion detallada del proceso. Por algun motivo no logro que el sistema formatee bien mi respuesta pero el script esta probado y funciona sin problemas.

Comment: Una solución elegante ademas de comprensible para los noveles como yo.